# How can I limit the amount of words displayed from a Ruby string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

the Ruby code is below:

```
<%= product.advert_text -%>
```

What script can limit the amount of words?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to limit to a certain number of words, the easiest way is going to be to split on space and then join the desired number of words back into a string.

```
<%=product.advert_text.split.slice(0, limit).join(" ") -%>
```

Answer (score 15):

Since you are working with Rails, you can use the [truncate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M002277) method.

So, something like:

```
<%= truncate(product.advert_text, :length => 20) -%>
```

The `:length` option sets the # of characters to truncate at & will add ellipses at the end (you can override the default ellipses with the `:omission` option - see the documentation on my link).